# How do you keep a fixed header on top of the page when pinch/zoom when the body is scrolling underneath?

Tags: css, header, css-position

I have a web page with a fixed position header (Z-index:1000).  The body of the page is a lower z-index and scrolls underneath the header.

When I pinch/zoom the page on my smartphone, the header is detached from the webpage and zooms separately, overlapping the body.

I want the header to remain on top of the page attached.

Here is the link:  [TEST PAGE](http://www.givemehope.com/test.htm)

Answer (score 1):

This has always been an issue with touchscreen devices.  I don't believe there is a pure css solution for this, since the pinching/zooming will move the entire viewport, and not just the element that you are touching.  You may have to resort to a javascript based solution.  See here for an extensive list.  http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/